# Как отработать js-функцию после загрузки картинки?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая проверяет размеры картинки, как сделать так, чтобы она выполнялась после загрузки картинки. Иначе возвращаются пустые параметры.

Comment: `<img ... onload="checkSize(this)"`

Comment: Игорь, спасибо. Однако у меня картинки добавляются с помощью js и нужно выполнить скрипт, поле загрузки всех картинок.

Comment: Исправьте/дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос. По возможности, включив фрагменты относящихся к вопросу html и javascript'a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');
img.onload = function() {
  alert('Width: ' + this.width + 'px. Height: ' + this.height + 'px');
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете назначить обработчик события `onload`:

```js
function checkSize(anImage) {
  alert($(anImage).width() + " x " + $(anImage).height());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img onload="checkSize(this)" src="https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
```