# Как поймать событие загрузки картинки?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть большой графический файл (карта) на 5 Mb который грузится иногда заметно (до 10 секунд, особенно если интернет проседает), как запускать скрипт только после полной загрузки этого файла если загрузки всей страницы полностью ждать не хочется? (которая document.ready)

Comment: событие `onload`

Comment: @Grundy onload для конкретного тега img?

Comment: да, для того, который нужно обязательно дождаться

Comment: @Grundy а чего молотом не машешь?  тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595277/191482 ты же закрыл дубликатом  на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/529051/191482  .... и вообще в поиске еще что-то валяется на эту тему  ........ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8  .... типа [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589034/Как-отработать-js-функцию-после-загрузки-картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/589034/191482) и прочее

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, там была суть в том, что несколько картинок по порядку должны были грузиться. А тут всего одна и по сути не нужна очередь из promise.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но если проголосуешь за дубликат - я бамкну

Comment: @Grundy Ну вон из 589034 можно дубликатить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сойдет